# como criar um app React Native no windows e testar no Iphone

Tags: android, ios, windows, react-native, emulador

Galera, estou programando um app RN no windows e não tenho macbook mas tenho um iphone e gostaria de testar o app no aparelho, como poderia proceder?

Vi alguns comentarios de ter acessar um mac virtualmente, mas essa seria a melhor opção atualmente? se sim, qual site indicam para fazer isso?

Não seria possivel continuar programando no windows, emulando no proprio computador  um sistema android e alternar testando no meu aparelho iphone?

Obrigada

Answer (score 4):

Infelizmente isso não seria possível.

Uma das alternativas, como você mesma citou, seria alugar um Mac. Um dos sites que permite fazer isso seria o seguinte.

https://www.macincloud.com

Se você já tiver a conta de desenvolvedor da Apple (que é paga anualmente), você pode criar o seu aplicativom subir para a Apple Store (sem publicar) e compartilhar com algumas pessoas através do TestFlight. Desta forma, você consegue baixar no seu aparelho e testar. Mas, para testar durante o desenvolvimento, pode utilizar o emulador disponível no Xcode.

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Se você quer criar aplicativos para IOS e Android com React Native, o ideal é fazer tudo no Mac. Alternar entre sistemas é muito trabalhoso.

Algumas pessoas criam uma máquina virtual no Windows usando o VirtualBox e instalam o Mac OS nela. Apesar de funcionar, isso não é recomendado.